Disable customer shipping adresses if it not belong from US magento2
I want to Disable shipping adresses if it's not matched with usa country or shipping origin country on checkout page magento2
I want to know how we can overwrite knockout file related to this task in magento
For example if we have different shipping address but some adresses are not belong to shipping origin that address radion button. Disable and can not proceed for checkout
enter image description hereenter code here
/**

Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

define([
'underscore',
'ko',
'mageUtils',
'uiComponent',
'uiLayout',
'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'
], function (_, ko, utils, Component, layout, addressList, customer) {
'use strict';
var defaultRendererTemplate = {
    parent: '${ $.$data.parentName }',
    name: '${ $.$data.name }',
    component: 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default',
    provider: 'checkoutProvider'
};

return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/list',
        visible: addressList().length > 0,
        rendererTemplates: []
    },

    /** @inheritdoc */
    initialize: function () {
        this._super()
            .initChildren();

        var self = this;
        addressList.subscribe(function (changes) {
            changes.forEach(function (change) {
                if (change.status === 'added') {
                    if (self.shouldRenderAddress(change.value)) {
                        self.createRendererComponent(change.value, change.index);
                    }
                }
            });
        }, this, 'arrayChange');

        return this;
    },

    /** @inheritdoc */
    initConfig: function () {
        this._super();
        // Initialize the list of child components that are responsible for address rendering
        this.rendererComponents = [];

        return this;
    },

    /** @inheritdoc */
    initChildren: function () {
        var self = this;
        _.each(addressList(), function (address, index) {
            // Check if address should be rendered based on conditions
            if (self.shouldRenderAddress(address)) {
                self.createRendererComponent(address, index);
            }
        });

        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Determines if an address should be rendered based on conditions.
     * 
     * @param {Object} address
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    shouldRenderAddress: function (address) {
         // Check conditions: USA address and storeId 4, or non-USA address and storeId not 4
        if ((address.countryId === 'US' && window.checkout.storeId == 4) ||
            (address.countryId !== 'US' && window.checkout.storeId != 4)) {
            return true;
        }

        // Return false by default (addresses that do not meet the conditions)
        return false;

       
    },

    /**
     * Create a new component that will render the given address in the address list
     *
     * @param {Object} address
     * @param {*} index
     */
    createRendererComponent: function (address, index) {
        var rendererTemplate, templateData, rendererComponent;

        // Use default renderer template
        rendererTemplate = _.extend({}, defaultRendererTemplate);

        // Populate template data
        templateData = {
            parentName: this.name,
            name: index
        };

        // Create renderer component
        rendererComponent = utils.template(rendererTemplate, templateData);
        _.extend(rendererComponent, {
            address: ko.observable(address)
        });
        layout([rendererComponent]);
        this.rendererComponents[index] = rendererComponent;
    }
});

});

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please check my image. For non USA users i want to remove or can disable address
